# Using bash "wait" to exit as soon as one of the background processes terminate

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a bash script that forks two background server processes (whose termination means a problem), and this script would exit **as soon as one of them terminates** (without waiting for the other one).

Here's what I tried so far:

#### Attempt 1

Using bash `wait` directive. This didn't work because it still waits for both processes to complete. In my case, I'm running two server processes, so if they complete, it means something is wrong, so I should exit this script altogether.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

./server1 &
pid1="$!"
./server2 & 
pid1="$!"

wait "$1"
wait "$2"
```

#### Attempt 2

The same as above, but instead just say `wait` without specifying pid. Does the same behavior.

```
...
pid2="$!"
wait
```

#### Attempt 3

I tried using sub-shells and exiting from there. But the `exit` applies only to the sub-shell, so we still wait for both background processes to finish:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

( ./server1 || echo crash1; exit 1 ) &
( ./server2 || echo crash2; exit 2 ) &
wait
```

---

Is there way to achieve this (forking two server processes in the background, and exiting as soon as one of them finishes) in bash?

Comment: On Bash v4 (or greater) just one `wait -n` is all you need. On Bash v3 you might do it by playing with signals.

Comment: did you mean to use `$!` for all of your variable assignments? And the 2nd `pid1=` should maybe be `pid2=`?

Comment: @LL3, mind adding an answer?

Comment: @Jeff, yep sorry just a mistake on the question, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wait -n
```

From `help wait` in `bash`:

> If the `-n` option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
>       returns its exit status.

Using `wait -n` will wait for the *next* job to terminate.  This means that if either of your two background jobs terminates, the call to `wait -n` will return.  You will get the exit status of that job as the exit status of `wait -n`, but you won't know which one of the jobs terminated.

The `-n` option for `wait` was added in `bash-4.3-alpha`.